# Vim remapping ctrl in Insert mode

Tags: vim

Coming from Emacs, I really miss a quick way to get to the end of the line.
I know about <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> but would honestly prefer a single command to get to the end of the line while in *Insert mode*.

Is there a way to map <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd> to *Normal mode* + <kbd>A</kbd> while in *Insert mode*?

Comment: I think you're only going to make yourself unhappy if you try to make vim work just like emacs.

Comment: @MattBall totally agree but I still need to 'transition', I think asking for Emacs EOL isn't complete blasphemy :)

Comment: `End` could be away from the typer position, like arrow keys. a `Ctrl+e` allows you to keep hands on the typing area.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
:imap <silent> <C-e> <ESC>A
```

`imap` stands for Insert mode, `<C-e>` is the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> and <kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> is the action to perform.

You can add it to your `vimrc`, without `:`.

Answer (score 5):

An alternative solution without leaving insert mode inside the mapping:

```
:inoremap <C-E> <End>
:inoremap <C-A> <Home>
```

Check out what you lose by remapping [`CTRL-E`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#i_CTRL-E) and [`CTRL-A`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#i_CTRL-A), though!

Comment: I am thinking of mapping ctrl-hjkl such that I can move across panes similar to what I do in normal mode. I probably have to chain some commands such as <ESC>, <cntrl-j> to <ctrl-j> in insert mode. What is the difference between `inoremap` that you mentioned that `imap` that dave mentioned here:https://stackoverflow.com/a/11485928/4752883